# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Nombreproductos ==' some product '

Tags: java, mysql

I have this code:

```
try{

        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String db = "jdbc:odbc:Driver=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=Productosh.mdb";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(db, "", "");
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet hola = s.executeQuery("select Precioventau from Productos where Nombreproductos == '"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"'");
        while (hola.next()){
            double preciou = hola.getDouble("Precioventau");
            System.out.println(preciou);
            jTextField5.setText(String.valueOf(preciou));
        }


    } catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Supossed to set in a textfield the result of the query.
It does raise an exception but I can't figure how to solve it.

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft] [ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]
>   Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Nombreproductos
>   ==' some product '

But `Nombreproductos` is a field in table `Productos`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing strings in SQL you can use '=' or the keyword `LIKE`

```
ResultSet hola = s.executeQuery("select Precioventau from Productos where Nombreproductos = '"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"'");
while (hola.next()){

ResultSet hola = s.executeQuery("select Precioventau from Productos where Nombreproductos like '"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"'");
while (hola.next()){
```

The difference between '=' and `LIKE` is '=' must be the same match. 'LIKE' is able to use wildcards.

Comment: The error was the fact that SQL does not use the == operator so it did not recognize what you were wanting it to do. 

You were essentially saying SELECT blah FROM blah WHERE blah. You didn't provide the correct way of saying WHERE blah EQUALS blah. Sorry for the excessive use of blah

Comment: Oh i see, thanks forma the like and dont worry about blah

Answer (score 0):

There is no `==` operator in SQL; you can compare for equality with `=`.  Try

```
"select Precioventau from Productos where Nombreproductos = '"+
    jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"'"
```

Comment: When i use just one equal sing shows me an inválid state of cursor :/ so i try using double == and ir shows me this error